# How to solve Chrome mobile browser address bar css issue with position fixed element?

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile, position, fixed

I get a very strange bug on Android Chrome mobile browser because of the URL bar / address bar of the browser. The website with the other common browsers work very well.

There is a scroll-to-top button (video: https://streamable.com/21iu2) that positioned fixed and when this Chrome address bar appears, the button does not work, only if I touch the screen above the button...

Scroll-to-top button css:

```
#scrollToTop {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 1rem;
  z-index: 9997;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.14901960784313725);
  background: rgba(52, 58, 64, .5);
  cursor: pointer;

  &:hover {
    background: rgba(52, 58, 64, 0.83);
  }

  i {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 800;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
}
```

Component (Angular 6):

```
import {Component, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-scroll-to-top',
  template: `
    <a *ngIf="isVisible" id="scrollToTop" class="rounded" (click)="scrollToTop()">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./scroll-to-top.component.scss']
})
export class ScrollToTopComponent {
  isVisible = false;

  @HostListener('window:scroll', [''])
  onWindowScroll() {
    this.isVisible = window.pageYOffset > 100 ? true : false;
  }

  scrollToTop(): void {
    window.scroll({top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
  }
}
```

How can I solve these issues? Or how can I 'solve' these with workaround?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Welcome to Posting on Stack Overflow. Please include the relevant source code in the post and see these guidelines [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I added video and source:)

Comment: @PaRi i wonder how you solve that???